Concise non-destructive mounting of LVM2 from an Old Disk
I reinstalled Fedora and kept the old disk with my data as an archive of my earlier work.  Now I want to recover some of those old files.
There are posts that describe how to mount an LVM2, but so far all of those posts seem to require vgrename, and some caution that the disk is then not bootable.  Some of those then add a length procedure to patch it up manually to be bootable again in some fashion.  That seems an unacceptable risk since this disk is intended as an archive.
How do we temporarily mount a directory from an old LVM2 volume without altering the disk, and especially how do we do this in a way that does not leave it unbootable as a system disk?
Thank you

I would try only a vgimport -ay and check if there is a name collision between Volume Groups at first. In the case there is no collision, you should able to see your VG in the blivet-gui (utility for disk Management) coming with Fedora.
